# Problem saving multiple models at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a goal completion application, where users have many goals, and goals have many tasks. I'm trying to get it such that a user can create tasks and goals at the same time. The problem I'm running into is that the goal is saving just fine, but the task which belongs to it isn't saving at all. From all the other similar questions about this topic I think the actual form is fine, but the create action in the goals controller is messed up. Sorry if this seems like a trivial problem, I'm still really new to rails.

the form

```
<%= form_for @goal do |f| %>     

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>     
  <p>    
    <%= f.label :content, "Goal" %>     
    <%= f.text_field :content %>     
  </p>     
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |ff| %>          
  <p>    
    <%= ff.label :content, "Task" %>          
    <%= ff.text_field :content %>          
  </p>     
  <% end %>     
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>     
<% end %>
```

goals controller

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @goal = @user.goals.build(params[:goal])
  if @goal.save
    flash[:success] = "Goal created!"
    redirect_to user_path(current_user) 
  else
    render 'new'
  end 
end 

def new 
  @title = "New Goal"
  @goal = Goal.new
  @goal.tasks.build
end
```

Comment: Show me the html output from your view and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @goal = @user.goals.build(params[:goal])
  @goal.tasks.build(params[:goal][:task]) # Here I assume params[:goal][:task] will return an hash with task fields as keys.
```

Comment: After implementing that I ran into validation problems that I shouldn't have, saying the goal and content were both blank when they aren't, so they don't save. Removing the validations on the Task model causes them to save, but the name of the Task still remains nil. I'm not quite sure where to go from here because clearly the validations should pass just fine...